# Looping calculations from data frames

Tags: sql, r

I have a large dataset coming in from SQLdf. I use `split` to order it by an index field from the query and `list2env` to split these into several data frames. These data frames will have names like 1 through 178. After splitting them, i want to do some calculations on all of them. How should i "call" a calculations for 1 through 178 (might change from day to day) ?

Simplification: one dataset becomes n data frames splitted on an index (like this):

```
return date return benchmark_returen index 
28-03-2014  0.03     0.05             6095
```

with typically 252 * 5 obs (IE: 5 years)

then i want to split these on the index into (now 178 dfs)

and perform typically risk/return analytics from the PerformanceAnalytics package like for example chart.Histogram or charts.PerformanceSummary.

In the next step i would like to group these and insert them into a PDF for each Index. (the graphs/results that is).

Comment: Unless you show the code you've tried, provide at least a (representative) sample of your data, and preferably show us what the desired result looks like, you are unlikely to get much help.

Comment: Like jihoward said, you should provide an eaxmplae of your data and what exactly you want to perform on it with the PerformanceAnalytics package. But from what I understand, you don't need to use `list2env` at all. When you perfrom `split`, you are receiving a list and it is exactly the best form to leave it for a `for` loop as it works best with lists. see [Hadleys Memory usage in R article](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Comment: sorry guys, first post! I will try to edit my the post. My question concerns the naming of the created df`s from the split() in order to program this into an executable routine.

So when i am returned with these objects i wonder how to "call" them in the for loop. 

Cheers for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the question lacks a proper example but indexing of environments can be done as with lists. In order to construct a list the have digits as index values one needs to use backticks, and arguments to `[[` when accessing environments need to be characters

```
> mylist <- list(`1`="a", `2`="b")
> myenv <- list2env(mylist)
> myenv$`1`
[1] "a"
> myenv[[as.character(1)]]
[1] "a"
```

If you want to extract values (and then possibly put them back into the environment:

```
sapply(1:2, function(n) get(as.character(n), envir=myenv) )
[1] "a" "b"

myenv$calc <- with(myenv,  paste(`1`, `2`))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! this isn't exactly what I'm after.
You have a 1 row example of my output and thus you can assume that this result is reiterated for n times with function split() and list2env() --- leaving n separate lists where i want to perform calculations/charts on each of these elements/lists of the kind as highlighted above in the example (chart.histogram() and chart.Performance())

Comment: Your understanding of the level of detail expected of questioners on SO is flawed. Post some real examples! Learn to use `dput`.